# Why won't iPad connect to my mail server?

Tags: ipad

I have just got an iPad and tried to set up my mail server.

I have a server that has SMTP on port 25 and IMAP configured on the default port 143, nothing special.

In addition, I have port 144 for secure IMAP and 26 for secure SMTP. SSL is a self signed certificate for a custom root that is installed in all devices that allow it.

I use SSL exclusively here and every laptop, desktop and other device works fine with it.

I first tried to set the iPad up with this, but when it did not work, I deleted the account and tried the non secure standard 25/143.

After main attempts (and failures) I did discover that I can send messages fine on both standard and the secure SMTP (indicating no problems with the SSL certificate).

I turned on logging on my mail server and found the message

```
TCPConnection - SSL handshake with client failed. Error code: 2, Message: End of file,
```

I get this when trying both SSL on and off.

I tested it on an iPod touch that was here and it works fine on both Imap Secure and standard.

Thanks in advance!

edit---

I found the enterprise tool, and managed to pull a log. I have cleared the log, then go in to mail and the following occurs:

```
Thu Nov 11 15:33:50 unknown MobileMail[47] <Warning>: Error: Tried to get message at 0, but we only have 0 messages.
Thu Nov 11 15:33:50 unknown MobileMail[47] <Warning>: Error: Tried to get message at 0, but we only have 0 messages.
Thu Nov 11 15:33:50 unknown MobileMail[47] <Warning>: Error: Tried to get message at 0, but we only have 0 messages.
Thu Nov 11 15:33:50 unknown MobileMail[47] <Warning>: Error: Tried to get message at 0, but we only have 0 messages.
Thu Nov 11 15:33:50 unknown MobileMail[47] <Warning>: Error: Tried to get message at 0, but we only have 0 messages.
Thu Nov 11 15:33:50 unknown MobileMail[47] <Warning>: Error: Tried to get message at 0, but we only have 0 messages.
Thu Nov 11 15:33:50 unknown configd[24] <Debug>: CaptiveNetworkSupport:UIAllowedNotifyCallback:63 uiallowed: true
Thu Nov 11 15:35:14 unknown MobileMail[47] <Warning>: Error: Tried to get message at 0, but we only have 0 messages.
Thu Nov 11 15:35:14 unknown MobileMail[47] <Warning>: Error: Tried to get message at 0, but we only have 0 messages.
Thu Nov 11 15:35:14 unknown MobileMail[47] <Warning>: Error: Tried to get message at 0, but we only have 0 messages.
Thu Nov 11 15:35:14 unknown MobileMail[47] <Warning>: ERROR: MFMessageErrorDomain/Socket Read - The connection to the server "ezpcltd.com" failed.
```

Straight after the last line, the device flashes the "Cannot Get Mail" message.

Comment: Strange. Have you restarted the iPad? (like full hardware shutdown and startup?)

Comment: Yes - I tried this, but not luck :(

Comment: If you go with your Mobile Safari (in the iPad) to the URL: ezpcltd.com do you get a response? (I do get one here)

Comment: @Martin Marconcini - Yes, no problem what so ever - I also have tried with an Iphone and Ipod touch, no problems what so ever, however this has now been solved after a hell of a lot of trouble and almost an entire days work... I will post how I did it when I have a bit of time to write it up.

Answer (score 1):

I did originally fix this problem, but it has resurfaced.

I have written a great deal about this problem at my blog... (would paste directly, but pictures will not show up).

http://blog.williamhilsum.com/2010/11/ipad-update-and-more-problems-with-mail.html

The blog will show how I fixed the original problem, therefore is an answer, however, it also shows the new (related) problem.

If anyone has a good fix that will solve everything once and for all, please write another answer!